# Image disappears in my docx document after altering and saving it

Tags: xml, docx

I'm generating a docx file using Java (I'm not using any API) and It's working fine except with images.

I can add an image and generate the file and it does appear there exactly as I wanted. But whenever I alter the document, save, close then re-open the image disappears. All I see is a transparent square. When I open the document as .zip (after altering and saving) the image won't be there anymore.

This is my word/document.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document
    xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:ind w:firstLine="0.0" />
                <w:jc w:val="left" />
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:pict>
                <v:shape id="myShape1" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:200; height:200">
                    <v:imagedata r:id="rId10" />
                </v:shape>
            </w:pict>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6" />
            <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId7" />
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906.0" w:h="16838.0" />
            <w:pgMar w:top="1417.0" w:right="1701.0" w:bottom="1417.0"
                w:left="1701.0" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
            <w:cols w:space="708" />
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

This is my word/_rels/document.xml.rels:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable"
        Target="fontTable.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId3"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings"
        Target="webSettings.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId7"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer"
        Target="footer1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId2"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings"
        Target="settings.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId1"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles"
        Target="styles.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId6"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header"
        Target="header1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId5"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes"
        Target="endnotes.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId4"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes"
        Target="footnotes.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId9"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme"
        Target="theme/theme1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId10"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"
        Target="media/image10.jpg" />
</Relationships>
```

After I save my docx this is how my word/_rels/document.xml.rels is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer"
        Target="footer1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId3"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings"
        Target="webSettings.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId7"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header"
        Target="header1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId2"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings"
        Target="settings.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId1"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles"
        Target="styles.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId6"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"
        Target="ooxWord://word/media/image10.jpg" TargetMode="External" />
    <Relationship Id="rId5"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes"
        Target="endnotes.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId10"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme"
        Target="theme/theme1.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId4"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes"
        Target="footnotes.xml" />
    <Relationship Id="rId9"
        Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable"
        Target="fontTable.xml" />
</Relationships>
```

If that's not enough I can upload my docx file.

Comment: Is your image media/image10.jpg still in the docx?

Comment: No, after I alter, save and close it gets deleted too. But it's still in my document.xml.rels but its rId is 6. Just edited my post and added the new word/_rels/document.xml.rels.

Comment: Your document.xml and document.xml.rels seem ok. It seems like a problem during the zipping or unzipping process. Could you please post your code of the zipping/unzipping?

Comment: I probably should have said it when I posted: I'm not zipping it in Java (yet). I'm generating all those XMLs then I zip them with Winrar then I change its extension to .docx.

Comment: Could you please send the document before and after the process?

Comment: I just left my job. I'll do it tomorrow as soon as I'm back there.

Comment: ok, i'll have a look at it when you post it

Comment: How are you altering the document and saving it?  What program are you using to assert that it appears exactly as you want it in the first place?  Please update your question with these details.